# What data type to be used in SQL to store very high negative exponential value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a Stored Procedure and In my SQL Code there is a value in denominator which comes out to be approx. e^-33 and in turn SQL round it off to zero which results dividebyzero error thrown by Stored Proc. I am using data type as decimal(38,10). Please suggest the data type which should be used to get the exact value? Can SQL store such small values?

Comment: `FLOAT`, but there's only 15-16 digits precision. In Oracle there's `NUMBER` which can be used a s a kind of super-float with 38 digits precision.

Comment: You might consider taking the log and storing the log instead of the original value.

Comment: Yes but float is NOT the correct type if you want precise values. If  you need precise values you should consider using decimal or numeric and increase the precision to your requirements. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: Be careful when you say "exact value": e^-33 would be an irrational number.

Comment: As others have pointed out, `float` is capable of representing such a number approximately.  My guess, though, is that there may be an alternate method of expressing the calculation that you want to run that doesn't involve dividing by incredibly small numbers (manipulating the log of the numerator and denominator for example).

Answer (score 1):

With `DECIMAL` it's not possible to store the EXACT value of numbers that low. You'd have to use `FLOAT` which represents an approx. value.

If you use float there should be no "divide by zero" error. If I run the following sample code in SQL-Server:

```
DECLARE @var FLOAT;
DECLARE @var2 FLOAT;

SET @var = POWER(CAST(2.71828 AS FLOAT),-100);
SET @var2 = POWER(CAST(2.71828 AS FLOAT),-2);

Select @var/@var2
```

...the result would be 2,74896621369795E-43. It's not possible to store values that low as EXACT values whith `DECIMAL`.

Howewer if you just want to handle the "divide by zero" error you can do the following:

```
DECLARE @var DECIMAL(38,35);
DECLARE @var2 DECIMAL(38,35);

SET @var = 5.0;
SET @var2 = 0.0;

Select ISNULL(@var / NULLIF(@var2,0.0),0.0)
```

`NULLIF` returns `NULL` if both expressions (`@var2` and `0.0`) are equal. The surrounding `ISNULL` checks if the expression (`NULLIF(...)`) equals `NULL` and if so, it'll return 0.0 as replacement for `NULL`. So the `SELECT` shows 0.000000 as a result

Comment: Thanks Nate for your answer. But the problem still persists though i also used NULLIFs() in my code to avoid dividebyzero error. But again it will give you null or zero if you use ISNULL(). The point is how to get the exact value because the denominator is having very less value so the result would be very high i.e. approx. e^+34. which is my output from the stored procedure. I tried scale to 35 places and that also returned zero rather than the actual small value (e^-33).